# Digital Performer - Copying Between Projects

Tags: audio-recording, audio, daw

Is it possible to export an entire chunk/sequence from one Digital Performer project file and import it into another?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you export to wave each track at a time for more control. I don't really use DP but if you choose all of the tracks at the same time i believe it will only create one big merged wave file.

After having the exported wave/s its very easy to import into another DAW (drag and drop usually)